# Clarifying feature references in WFS?

Tags: wfs, xml, ogc, ows

I want to clarify something about feature references in WFS 2.0 standard ([OGC 09-025r1 document](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=39967))

Do I understand correctly, that "resolve feature reference" means "get (remote or local) feature by xlink and include it to response results subset"?

Accordingly, remote feature - feature linked by "http://(.*)#myfeature.1", local - feature located on the same (requested) server

Comment: I couldn't find that exact phrase in the referenced standard, but terms and definitions 4.23 resolve says: `retrieval of a referenced resource and its insertion into a server-generated response document
NOTE
The insertion may be accomplished by either replacing the reference in-line with a copy of the resource or by
relocating the reference to point to a copy of the resource that has been placed in the response document.`

Comment: @nmtoken , thanks, this clarifies the situation somewhat. But I still do not really understand what a local link is and what a remote link is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find that exact phrase (`"resolve feature reference"`) in the referenced standard, but the answers are I think in the terms and definitions section.

> 4.23 resolve
>   retrieval of a referenced resource and its insertion into a server-generated response document
>
> NOTE The insertion may be accomplished by either replacing the reference in-line with a copy of the resource or by relocating the reference to point to a copy of the resource that has been placed in the response document.

Similarly

> 4.13 local resource
>   resource that is under the direct control of a system
>
> NOTE In this International Standard, the system is a web feature service and the resource is held in a data store that is directly controlled by that service

and

> 4.20 remote resource
>   resource that is not under direct control of a system
>
> NOTE In this International Standard, the system is a web feature service. The resource is not held in any data store that is directly controlled by that service and thus cannot be directly retrieved by the service.